# Uso e comprensione dell'espressione "essere difettosi"

Tags: word-usage

Credo che pressoché ovunque le persone parlino di "carattere difettoso" per riferirsi ai  comportamenti altrui quando questi appaiano sgradevoli per qualche ragione.

Sarei interessato a sapere se l'espressione "sei un po' difettoso" è comunemente capita nel senso indicato, cioè "hai un carattere difettoso", ovvero se si tratta di forma mutuata, in alcune regioni, da dialetti locali.

Comment: Di sicuro non è vero che si usa ovunque.

Comment: I've never heard *carattere difettoso*, to be honest. Please, note that it's *pressoché* and not *pressocchè*.

Comment: @martina, strano! E se il carattere di qualcuno *difettasse* di qualche qualita', tu come diresti (se non usi dire *carattere difettoso*) ?

Comment: @egreg, thanks! But the responsible was kiamla, not I, though.

Comment: @KyriakosKyritsis Truly, I just replaced replaced _e'_ with _è_; it was you who wrote _pressocche'_. I didn't change a correct word with a wrong one.

Comment: @KyriakosKyritsis Beh, se voglio dire che uno manca di qualcosa nel carattere gli dico "manchi di..."; non uso e non ho mai sentito la forma "carattere difettoso". Se ti riferisci, come da domanda, a comportamenti sgradevoli, si usa la forma standard "caratteraccio/brutto carattere".

Comment: Mai sentito *difettoso* in riferimento al carattere di qualcuno. Possibile sia un'espressione dialettale?

Comment: @kiamla, I didn't want to say you have done that, but only that you used 'è', not I.

Comment: @nico, ma se *carattere difettoso* significa *carattere che difetta di qualche qualita'*, non vedo cosa ci sia di dialettale nel dire *carattere difettoso*.

Comment: @Kyriakos Kyritsis: decisamente non è comune in Lombardia, mi chiedevo se fosse comune in altre regioni. Personalmente per me *difettoso* si riferisce ad un apparecchio che non funziona, non ad un carattere che difetta di qualche qualità.

Comment: I agree with @nico: I have never heard _carattere difettoso_ being used. I would understand _difettoso di gola_ to mean "not being health." It seems that [_carattere difettoso_](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=carattere+difettoso&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccarattere%20difettoso%3B%2Cc0) is used, though.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: se però guardi le citazioni esatte ti accorgi che spesso non si riferisce al carattere di una persona. Ad esempio: *il carattere difettoso di un prodotto*, *il carattere difettoso della conoscenza e della memoria umane*, *il gene che trasmette un carattere difettoso o una malattia*, *il carattere difettoso di una tale procedura*, *il carattere difettoso del genere operistico*, *il carattere difettoso delle merci* etc.

Comment: @nico Non ricordavo come vedere le citazioni. `:)` L'unica che mi sembra potrebbe azzeccare è "il carattere difettoso dei soggetti parlanti", ma è comunque una su tante.

Answer (score 1):

I heard it many times, often even had it said to me. I live near Milan.

Even though "carattere difettoso" can mean what you mean, is far more common to indicate that that particular person doesn't have some kind of quality or manners.

For example, if two friends are talking about a common friend who get's angry very often they can easily say:

> "Sai che è un po' difettoso sotto quell'aspetto... "

In the meaning that he lacks self-control.

I must say though that it isn't so common as you think. Even here in Milan there are people who doesn't use this kind of expression.